# Target a specific page/template in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a website with a fixed top-bar that displays a certain logo. I used the following script in jQuery to show/hide the logo after scrolling a number of pixels:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 63) {
  jQuery('.top-bar-logo').fadeIn();
} else {
  jQuery('.top-bar-logo').css({
'display': 'none'
});
}
}); 
</script>
```

The above script works well but it applies to every page in the website. So what I'd like to do now is to customize this script for a specific page/template. For example, I'd like to target the 'archive' template in jQuery and write a customized script for it. How can I do this?

I'm new to Wordpress development and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1

Use the body class. all templates will have a class representing them. ie: `body.archive`, `body.single`, `body.home`, etc. It will even have specific tax/post type classes for more granular control. Wrap your js function in something that checks for that body class. The following should do the trick:

**jQuery**

```
if ( $( 'body' ).first().hasClass( 'archive' ) ) {...}
```

**Plain JS**

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
if ( body.classList.contains('archive') ) {...}
```

**Note:** Body classes may be tweaked to your needs via the `body_class` filter, and the `body_class()` function must be on your body element.

**Function (make sure this is on your body element):**

body_class() | Function | WordPress Developer Resources
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

**Filter (Use this to manipulate):**

body_class | Hook | WordPress Developer Resources
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/

### Approach 2

You could also target this template in php and wrap your `wp_enqueue_script` for this file (as long as that is all that is in this file, and you need nothing else) in a conditional to check, ie: `is_archive()`, `is_single()`, `is_home()`.

**If you bundle your assets, use the first approach.**

Comment: @Berr see added jQuery example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @NoahMason. I tried the following but for some reason, it doesn't work: 

`<script> jQuery('document').scroll(function() { if ( jQuery( 'body' ).first().hasClass( 'archive' ) ) { var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop(); if (y > 63) { jQuery('.top-bar-logo').fadeOut(); } else { jQuery('.top-bar-logo').css({ 'display': 'block' }); } } }); </script>`

(And I did check that body_class() is already in my header.php)

Comment: I would wrap the whole thing with what I wrote, otherwise your scroll trigger will fire everywhere, even when not needed. after that, try in an incognito window. are you sure you are testing on an actual archive page?

Comment: yes, I tired it on the 'category' pages which use the generic 'archive' template, yet it seems I have missed something since I'm all new to this. In any case, I found another workaround directly in php instead of using jQuery. But thanks a lot for your suggestions :)